# I can't seem to link to html pages in a website using Django

Tags: python, html, django

I've been trying to develop a website using Django, I can open the homepage but whenever I click on a link that's supposed to direct me to another page, it won't work

```
def homepage(request):
return render(request,'AlzaidStudApp/homepage.html')
```

I'm not sure if I should add a new function for the rest of the pages or not

```
path('', views.homepage, name='home-page'),
```

The link in the HTML page is

```
<li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
```

I made a view function for the gallery page with

```
def gallery(request):
return render(request,'AlzaidStudApp/gallery.html' )
```

I also added a URL path:

```
path('gallery', views.gallery, name='gallery'),
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Using the URLconf defined in AlzaidStud.URLs, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
gallery [name='gallery']
[name='home-page']
```

Comment: can you show your code of urls,views and template so that i can check what the error is.

Comment: Give more information. What error if any are you getting?

Comment: If your URL name is "gallery" then your href becomes `<a href="{% url "gallery" %}">gallery</a>`